# How to zoom the image along with full screen when we tapped on it

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project i am adding one image on my View controller and when we click on this image then image need to zoom with full screen size for this i wrote some code but image is not fitting properly

According to my code screen is coming like below image but in want to fill that image entire screen help me

[image]

### My code is below:-

### ViewController1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;
    BOOL isFullScreen;
    CGRect prevFrame;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

### ViewController1.m

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    isFullScreen = FALSE;

    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen)];

    tap.delegate = self;

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    _imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen:)];
    tapper.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
}

-(void)imgToFullScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    if (!isFullScreen) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

            prevFrame = _imageView.frame;
            [_imageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = TRUE;
        }];
        return;
    }

    else{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [_imageView setFrame:prevFrame];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = FALSE;
        }];
        return;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set all on tap-gesture. you need to expand imageviewsize on tapgesture. or change the size of width and height according to your view controllers full screen's height and with.

Here is Example of tapgesture .

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)handleTemplateTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     imageview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: i have already done that above code that is  [_imageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];